# How much is this equipment worth?

Tags: equipment, cost

Being offered the following list of items for sale:

- Two 5-gallon glass carboys
- Thirty "Grolsh" (unsure of this term) bottles
- Bottle brush
- Funnel
- Bottle capping tool
- Bottling bucket w/ spicket
- Bottling wand
- Fittings and hoses
- CO2 canister
- CO2 regulator
- Two Cornelius kegs (look to be 5-gal)
- Diffusion stone

How much would this be worth do you think? Equipment is dirty and I'll have to clean it myself. Seller is offering $200.

Comment: Please mention in what country? And the currency is USD?  There are big differences depending where you live.

Comment: Grolsch is a brand of beer from the Netherlands.  Their bottles are usually green, with a ceramic lid with a rubber gasket, held in place with a metal attachment.  They're pretty nice, but beer in them should be kept out of sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the only thing of real value in the list are the CO2 regulators and the Cornelius kegs. They will only be useful if the seals are all intact. Are they worth $200? Possibly if in GOOD condition... If you have to clean the rest then it may just as well be bought new.

Answer (score 1):

That's a fair price if everything is in good condition, everything there is about 400-500 new as a kit.

Plastic fermenting parts can be risky used. If their history of use was with sours or Brett beers, they should only be used for that.

Some hidden costs.
Check the date on the co2 tank, it's about $12 to fill but add $40 or so to have certified if out of date.

Kegs can be rebuilt for $5 oring kit. Pipets can be $20 a keg but rarely fail.